# Can't account for space in String[]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fetch the data with a jquery call like this:

```
var row = $( grid ).find( 'tr.ui-row-ltr' );
var oldStatuses = $( row ).find( 'td[aria-describedby="' + 
                  grid[0].id + '_PersonStatuses"]' ).text().split( '|' );
```

oldStatuses should now be an array of statuses that was in `PersonStatuses`, in this particular case the only thing in `PersonStatuses` is a `&nbsp`, which shows up as

```
oldStatuses = [" "]
```

but I can't seem to check for it. I need to do stuff if oldStatuses isn't empty and I've tried these

```
if ( oldStatuses[i] != "" && 
     oldStatuses[i] != null && 
     oldStatuses[i] !== undefined && 
     oldStatuses[i] != " " &&
     oldStatuses[i] != "&nbsp" ) {
         doStuff();
}
```

Unfortunately it passes all of these and stuff is done when I don't want it to be. How can I catch this and why isn't `""` or `" "` able to catch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your string contains more than one whitespace. Try to use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove whitespaces from the beginning and from the end of the string:

```
if (oldStatuses[i] && oldStatuses[i].trim() != "") //...
```

Comment: that worked fantastically, thank you for the quick response. Do you know why it wasn't catching it with the `""` and `" "` ?

Comment: maybe your string looks like this: `"        " `(I typed multiple spaces but it is automatically formatted :-)